# How RabbitMQ fit well in my game/chat scenario?

Tags: rabbitmq

I know there are already lots of post regarding RabbitMQ and if it is appropriate or not to use it instead of XMPP, etc.. but stating that RabbitMQ is mandatory, how should i use RabbitMQ in my scenario?

here the specifications:
- there are many clients that can join one or more chatroom

- clients can create their own chat room and password protect them
- when a client disconnects there are 2 possible implementation: 1) he can't read previous message; 2) he can get message not older than 5 minutes before the login
- clients can send private message

now, giving this specification, what's the best practice using RabbitMQ?
What does RabbitMQ gives already implemented?
I'm using C# but my question is more about the software architecture

I've read something about different Excanges but i've doubt about what to use and how to organize queues.
Is Topic Exchange what i need? How should i implement it?
Should my consumers (so my game clients) create a queue every time they log to the server and bound a queue to a topic?

As you see i think I've not a clear understanding about how RabbitMQ manage this kind of things

A note about future improvements: RabbitMQ queue will be used to communicate game events to connected clients too, this is why simple chat protocol aren't taken into account

UPDATE:
maybe a fanout exchanger is what i need to dispatch message to all my queue that my clients will create when they login

and to create chatrooms i think would be better to create a server component that listen to a specific queue that clients sends to when they want to create a chat room

what's left out at this point is how to handle authentication to the rabbitmq instance and chat channel.
For chat channels i could delegate it to the server component (a user send to a queue "chat_authentication" the chatroom and password and the server component send to a named client queue if it's ok or not, but this doesnt' sounds secure to me if someone direct connect with a custom client to my rabbitMQ queues, so how should i implement authorization?

Comment: Your scenario would best be addressed by a combination of database, web service, and message broker. You need to broaden your design a bit.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create one fanout-exchange for every chat room and allow users to create their queues and bind to it.
2. For user authentication, you might think of integrating LDAP kind of solution.

You can also read my article: 
https://techietweak.wordpress.com/2015/08/14/rabbitmq-a-cloud-based-message-oriented-middleware/

To understand different exchanges in RabbitMQ.